# How to make a GET request in node.js sending a body?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I wold like to know how to make a GET request in node.js sending a body.

```
   const options = {
        hostname: 'localhost',
        port: 3000,
        path: '/abc',
        method: 'GET'
    }

    http.get(options, (res) => {
        res.on('data', (chunk) => {
            console.log(String(chunk))
        })
    })
```

Comment: There seems to be confusion. Are you trying to **make** a GET request with a body (which is very unusual), or **respond to** a GET request with a body (which is fairly common). Your title and your code seem to say you're trying to do the unusual thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it says in [the documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback):

> Since most requests are GET requests without bodies, Node.js provides this convenience method. The only difference between this method and `http.request()` is that it sets the method to GET and calls `req.end()` automatically.

So the answer is to use [`http.request`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback) directly. `http.request` has an example using POST, but it's the same for GET (start the request with `http.request`, use [`write`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_request_write_chunk_encoding_callback) to send the body data, use `end` when done sending data), other than the fact that (as noted above) GET usually doesn't have any body. In fact, [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.1) notes that:

> A payload within a GET request message has no defined semantics;
> sending a payload body on a GET request might cause some existing
> implementations to reject the request.

Answer (score 0):

Using the standard http:

```
`const http = require('http');

https.get('http://localhost:3000/abc', (resp) => {

  let data = '';

  // A chunk of data has been recieved.
  resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
    data += chunk;
  });

  // The whole response has been received. Print out the result.
  resp.on('end', () => {
    console.log(JSON.parse(data).explanation);
  });

}).on("error", (err) => {
  console.log("Error: " + err.message);
});`
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This doesn't **send** any body with the GET request. This **receives** the body of a GET **response**.

Comment: A GET request doesnt have a body in its request body except some query parameters, do you mean by the POST method maybe?

Comment: GET requests can have bodies. They basically never do, but they can. "How to make a GET request in node.js sending a body?" is fairly clear about what's being asked.

Answer (score 0):

Using Body in GET request is not recommended at all cause it is not the suggest behavior by HTTP 1.1 but you can use the following method:

```
const data = JSON.stringify({
  "userId": 1,
  "id": 1,
  "title": "delectus aut autem",
  "completed": false
});


const https = require('https')

const options = {
  hostname: 'jsonplaceholder.typicode.com',
  port: 443,
  path: '/posts',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Content-Length': data.length
  }
}

const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
console.log(`statusCode: ${res.statusCode}`)

res.on('data', (d) => {
        process.stdout.write(d)
    })
})

req.on('error', (error) => {
  console.error(error)
})

req.write(data)
req.end()
```